# What happened to the Master's blue laser powers?

Tags: doctor-who

What happened to the Master's blue laser powers and why doesn't (s)he have them in the Peter Capaldi episode with Missy?

Comment: Do you mean where you could see his skeleton when using them? We know that the Doctor got a whole new set of regenerations from the Time Lords. AFAIK we don't know what regeneration the Master was on. It's possible that she was given a whole new set of regeneration as well

Answer (score 6):

The Master did not normally have such powers. As a Timelord, he has broadly the same abilities as The Doctor.

The "blue laser powers" you are referring to, as seen in the story '*The End of Time*', were a result of a supernatural ritual meant to restore his life, but went wrong after it was sabotaged by Lucy Saxon. The life-force that he took from several humans, presumably meant to restore multiple lifetimes to him, was burning up much faster than it should have. When The Doctor saw a demonstration of these new abilities, he *warned* the Master that this would be to his detriment:

> DOCTOR: Please, let me help. You're burning up your own life force.

Evidently, the "lasers" we see shooting from his arms, which he used as a weapon and also to enable him to fly, was his own *life force*.

At the end of the story, the Master disappeared along with the other Timelords back through the portal they had opened, thus returning to the time-locked Time War. It is later stated in *The Doctor Falls* that the Timelords "cured" him, evidently resurrecting him and giving him a new regeneration cycle just as they had previously done during the time war.

Comment: No need to assume - it's specifically stated in The Doctor Falls that once he disappeared with the other Time Lords through the portal, they cured him and kicked him out.

Comment: @ElibE876 Thanks, I'd forgotten that. Quite a throwaway line for such a major plot element. Updated answer.

Comment: "*Quite a throwaway line for such a major plot element.*" - welcome to Moffat Who :-)